# interpolating variable to a complex string in python

Tags: python

I have a variable `group_array` like this

```
groups_array=[{"group": "18652_PDR"}, {"group": "11262_PDR"}, {"group": "3787_PDR"}, {"group": "4204_PDR"}]
```

I want to put the groups_array variable inside below string so I tried like this using the `f` method

```
data = f'{"request":{"streaming_type":"quote", "data":{"groups": {groups_array}}, "request_type":"subscribe", "response_format":"json"}}'
```

But am getting error `deeply nested` error

I want the string to be in below format after adding the variable

```
data = '{"request":{"streaming_type":"quote", "data":{"groups": [{"group": "18652_PDR"}, {"group": "11262_PDR"}, {"group": "3787_PDR"}, {"group": "4204_PDR"}]}, "request_type":"subscribe", "response_format":"json"}}'
```

Could someone tell me how can I properly do it in this case as there are too many `""` and `{}`?

Comment: Are you trying to create json?

Comment: @PatrickArtner trying to send the data to an api using websocket. This is the format it is expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the built-in json package. You would create a dictionary of your data and pass it to `json.dumps` to receive the json string.

```
import json
groups_array = [{"group": "18652_PDR"}, {"group": "11262_PDR"}, {"group": "3787_PDR"}, {"group": "4204_PDR"}]
data = {"request":
            {"streaming_type": "quote",
             "data": {
                     "groups": groups_array
             },
             "request_type": "subscribe",
             "response_format": "json"
             }
        }

data_json = json.dumps(data)
print(data)

# Output:
{'request': {'streaming_type': 'quote', 'data': {'groups': [{'group': '18652_PDR'}, {'group': '11262_PDR'}, {'group': '3787_PDR'}, {'group': '4204_PDR'}]}, 'request_type': 'subscribe', 'response_format': 'json'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign directly to dict and create a json (stringify it) if your request needs string:

```
import json

data = json.dumps({"request":{"streaming_type":"quote", "data":{"groups": groups_array}, "request_type":"subscribe", "response_format":"json"}})
```

Or if dictionary is also an option - pass it without json.dumps